# How can I use the Model's function?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a `TypeModel` model, and in it there is a :

```
class TypeModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=22)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    ch = models.CharField(max_length=44, null=True)

    def print(self, name, type):
        t = TypeModel.objects.create(name=name, type=type)
        print('success - ' + t.name)
```

I want to invoke the `print` method like this:

```
class TypeModelCreateAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    def post(self, request):

        TypeModel.print() # Can I invoke like this
        return Response(status=HTTP_200_OK, data='')
```

Whether I can invoke the function of model like this? if not, how to realize the Class method of model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be done with the [staticmethod annotation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod)

```
class TypeModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=22)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    ch = models.CharField(max_length=44, null=True)

    @staticmethod
    def print(name, type):
        t = TypeModel.objects.create(name=name, type=type)
        print('success - ' + t.name)
```

Please note, that a static method does not have the implicit `self` as first argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can use staticmethod:

```
@staticmethod
def print(name, type):
    t = TypeModel.objects.create(name=name, type=type)
    print('success - ' + t.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently `print`is defined as an instance method. You would have to create an instance of `TypeModel` to call it. Like:

```
model = TypeModel()
model.print()
```

Or you could use the `@staticmethod` decorator:

```
@staticmethod
def print(name, type):
    t = TypeModel.objects.create(name=name, type=type)
    print('success - ' + t.name)
```